# Can $p$-adic numbers be interpreted as the result of some summation method?

Tags: analysis, polynomials, power-series, p-adic-number-theory, formal-power-series

Perhaps an example of why I might want this information would clarify the question.

I know that Hensel's Lemma allows one to lift to roots of a polynomial to roots in $\mathbb{Q}$ *given a value for* $p$ and an initial guess.  My question is whether we can come up with a general rule that, say, limits the primes $p$ for which a rational polynomial can have roots in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.  If I were to try, e.g., substituting the series

$$\sum_{k\geq 0} a_kp^k$$

into a polynomial expression, then is it a simple matter of applying formal power series arithmetic, combining like powers of $p$, then forming a system of equations where the resulting coefficients for each $p^k$ must cancel?  Or am I missing some subtlety?

Comment: In the "simple matter of applying formal power series arithmetic", you might be forgetting that there are "carries" among the coefficients. Otherwise the ring $\mathbb Z_p$ would be isomorphic to $\mathbb F_p[[t]]$, which it is not (there is a point in exploiting the similarities of course).

Comment: That being said, I find your question unclear and in particular see little connection between the title and the question body.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is completely unclear.

Hensel lemma is saying that from $F\in \Bbb{Q}[x]$, that we transform in $f\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ monic  squarefree, there is some $N$ (easily computable but don't ask me its value) such that $f$ has a root in $\Bbb{Z}_p$ iff $f\bmod p^N$ has a root in $\Bbb{Z}/p^N\Bbb{Z}$. The correspondence is $a_N\to \lim_{n\to \infty } a_n$ where $a_{n+1}=a_n-f(a_n)/f'(a_n)$.